# How can I get Firebase Realtime Database to whitelist unwanted websites?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase Realtime Database to allow people in an art gallery to use their mobile phones to change a piece of generative art. The artwork is projected on the gallery wall and includes a QR code. When the user scans the QR code they go to a website which has a P5JS javascript app which they can enter some data and then press send. This sends it to the database. In the gallery another P5JS program is listening to the database and hears the new message and can display the data.

I am having problems with whitelisting.

The mobile phone app sits on a website
**[www.website1.com/mobile/index.html](http://www.website1.com/mobile/index.html)**

in the gallery the program is at this address
**[www.website1.com/gallery/index.html](http://www.website1.com/gallery/index.html)**

I want to make sure that the database can only read data from the **website1** domain.
How can I stop it receiving data from [www.website2.com](http://www.website2.com) ?

There is no authentication involved - the system is very open.

I have tried to follow the instructions on

Google Developer Console > APIs and Services > Credentials > (found the right) API Key > and set HTTP Referrers to

**[www.website1.com/](http://www.website1.com/)***

and waited 5 minutes......but nothing happened. I can still send data to the database from website2.

In Firebase I have added the website1 domain to Authentification > Sign In Method > Authorized domains

although I don't really expect that to help - as I said there is no Authentication required.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see here two potential solutions. You can decide what fits your need the best.

The first one would be to use the new App Check feature in Firebase. With that you can restrict the whole databse to only specific domains, apps and custom providers. You can find instructions for the setup [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/web).

If you need a more customisable solution where for example one domain needs only `read` access and the other `read` and `write` I would recommend to restrict the whole realtime database for read and write and create a REST API with Firebase Cloud Functions. With those you can restrict access to for specific domains and IP Adresses. You have full control as if you are using an express server. You can even use express to make the setup easier.